# How is magento 2 better than magento 1?

Tags: magento2, php, performance, zend-framework

I am just curious to know about **magento 2 performance and how it is better than magento 1.x versions**. Recently I started learning magento 2 and found that it is a whole new set of theory based on pure zend architecture. So I just want to know if it is better than Magento 1.x versions.

Comment: See article https://blog.amasty.com/magento-1-vs-magento-2-performance-comparison-speed-test-results/

Comment: There are may answer available for it just google for it.

Comment: "based on pure zend architecture" - if you are referring to Zend Framework, that's definitely not true. Magento was never a Zend Framework application, it just uses some of the Zend components. With `Magento\Framework` in Magento2, this is even more apparent than in Magento1.

Comment: Hi @fschmengler I did mentioned Zend Architecture not framework. Architecture by means folder structure which is way similar to ZF. [Magneto2 folder structure](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VtmFI.png) check here. As you can see controller, view, model everything is inside a folder unlike magento1.x.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This question may be opinion based but I'm just going to enlight some results from the offical [white paper regarding Magento 2 performance and scalability](https://magento.com/resources/white-paper-magento-2-site-performance-and-scalability-optimizations)

### Test Configuration

- Magento Enterprise Edition 2.0 with PHP7 and Varnish caching
- Magento Enterprise Edition 1.14.2 with PHP5.6 and Full-Page Caching

Comparison between Magento EE 1.14.2 and Magento EE 2.0 in the following scenarios:

- **Small merchant** with $1-$5M in online sales deployed on a single 4-core web node and a single database node. 25 simultaneous JMeter threads (representing 25 concurrent requests) were used to show site performance during a period of peak traffic, such as a sale.
- **Large merchant** with $50-$100M in online sales deployed on five 4-core web nodes and a single database node. 25 to 100 simultaneous JMeter threads (representing 25 to 100 concurrent requests) 
  were used to show site performance under increasing traffic loads.

[image]

### Small Merchant Deployment

Number of orders that can be processed per hour

[image]

Server Response Time

Catalog Browsing

[image]

Add to cart and Customer Checkout

[image]

### Large Merchant Deployment

Orders per Hour

[image]

Pages response time

[image]

[image]
[image]

You will probably find tons of comparison browsing the web, this is only one of them so I suggest you check the others that would help you get a good overview of the performance improvement.

Comment: The garphs are rare to find. Nicely compared. And there is a significant growth in performance in magento2. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Keep in mind those results were achieved with Varnish in front of Magento 2

Comment: more info needed. php versions, what varnish setup on both?

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga added the test config to the answer, everything is in the white paper by the way ;)

Comment: A bit unfair to use varnish in M2 and not in M1.

Comment: @LukeRodgers well I'm not the one who made the tests. I would say it's unfair to use PHP7 in M2 and not in M1 too but I assume that the use of both PHP7 and Varnish is because they are supported out of the box with M2

Comment: Yeah sorry wasn't meant to sound aggressive. It's a great answer from the white paper and I love it. It's just in fairness I would have liked for them to show cached/uncached page response times in the white paper also. Varnish is amazing and I use on M1 any time I can, but it feels a little disingenuous to say that M2 is 99% faster when it's really varnish.

Comment: @LukeRodgers no problem man I definitely agree with you and performance comparison has been a real debate in the Magento community lately

Comment: I think it's worth noting that Magento 1 performance was positively abysmal, and even if there is an honest ~39% improvement from 1 to 2, it's still awful in terms of throughput. 597 orders per hour is less than ten orders per minute; reasonably-designed software does not take six seconds to do something as technically trivial as processing an order in any deployment configuration, particularly given dedicated app and database servers (the product/checkout response times are fundamentally unacceptable on both versions).

Answer (score 4):

Magento 2.0 can be differentiated from its earlier version and has many unique features which can be listed as below:

Compatibility with Popular Platforms like MSSQL and Oracle.

Enhancement in performance and speed (magento 2.0 is 20 % faster then magento 1.x).

There are some significant changes in the structure of directory which reduce the complexity of structure (New directory called “pub” is introduced. These changes are done to provide a better structure for developer)

New technologies consist of the latest versions of PHP5.5x with PHP5.4.11,
Require Js, CSS3,HTML5 etc are included.

Better engagement with the community allows developer to setup automated test easily.

Comment: PHP 5.4 and Oracle are not supported(MySQL versions by Oracle and Percona are supported). With Magento 2.1RC1  PHP 5.5 is also not supported.  

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html